# How to define widgets with default values in Apostrophe CMS

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I want to add a widget that can't be removed from the page and contain some default text when it is not defined explicitly. 
I thought it should work something like this:

```
{{ 
   apos.singleton(data.page, 'headerTitle', 'apostrophe-rich-text', {
       def: 'Default Title'
   }) 
}}
```

Is there any way to do this with apostrophe widgets or I should create custom one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating your own widgets is pretty standard practice in Apostrophe but it doesn't address what to do if there is no widget yet in a singleton.

You can disable the removal of the singleton like this:

```
{{
  apos.singleton(data.page, 'headerTitle', 'apostrophe-rich-text', {
    controls: {
      removable: false,
      movable: false
    }
  })
}}
```

However an editor still has to click to initially add the widget to the page for each page.

So use this technique to provide default markup:

```
{% if apos.areas.isEmpty(data.page, 'headerTitle') %}
  <h4>Default Title</h4>
{% endif %}
{{
  apos.singleton(data.page, 'headerTitle', 'apostrophe-rich-text', {
    controls: {
      removable: false,
      movable: false
    }
  })
}}
```

Comment: antonys brings up a good point and I find myself trying to do the same thing. Maybe a widget isn't the correct construct. But, I want to build a global nav which populates itself automatically based on pages that have been created. The only way that I know of to get data into a view is to create a widget and implement `construct()`. But as you mentioned, when the site is deployed, someone still has to 'click' to add the nav...which seems odd. Is there a way to pull page data into the default layout? Extend apostrophe-templates or something?

Comment: welp, answered my own comment. Added an `index.js` to the apostrophe-templates module and queried for page data on `apostrophe-pages:beforeSend`
and was able to reference the data in the `/views/layout.html` `beforeMain` block. dope.

Comment: In A3 you will often prefer the new async components for tasks like this. It's quite far along already, you might want to start evaluating.