# Default value for images in apostrophe cms?

Tags: node.js, apostrophe, apostrophe-cms

I have a custom widget:

```
module.exports = {
    extend: 'apostrophe-widgets',
    label: 'Banner',
    addFields: [
      {
        name: 'bannerImg',
        type: 'attachment',
        label: 'Picture',
        def: 'http://via.placeholder.com/350x150'
      }
    ]
  };
```

And widget view:

```
<img class="logo" src="{{ apos.attachments.url(data.widget.bannerImg) }}" />
```

If I load image It's Ok I see it. But I don't have the default value. Also can I choose file from gallery without upload?

Comment: in official documentation I haven't found any information about defaults value. Also I have a problem with singleton type widget def value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spent a half of the day and found the solution:

as answered in: [How to define widgets with default values in Apostrophe CMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46673815/how-to-define-widgets-with-default-values-in-apostrophe-cms)

```
 {% if apos.areas.isEmpty(data.widget, 'bannerImg') %}
      <h1>Default Value</h1>
 {% endif %}
 {{ apos.singleton(data.widget, 'bannerImg', 'apostrophe-images', { limit: 1 }) }}
```

And also if we want to get href of this images:

```
{{ apos.attachments.url(apos.images.first(data.widget.bannerImg)) }}
```

Also in index.js I changed on:

```
  {
    name: 'bannerImg',
    type: 'singleton',
    label: 'Banner',
    widgetType: 'apostrophe-images',
    options: {
      limit: 1
    }
  },
```